# Can we always draw $n/3$ disjoint triangles from $n$ points in the plane in general position?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we are given $n$ points in the plane, where $n$ is a multiple of $3$ and no three of these points lie on a line. Is it possible to group all of these points into sets of three, so that if we draw the triangles formed by these sets, then no two of the triangles intersect?

---

Hi guys, I can visualise this question, but I have no idea how to approach it mathematically, any help?

Answer (score 10):

Given $n = 3k$ points, there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ ways to join them into lines and form unit vectors (2 for each line).
Pick a coordinate system such that none of these unit vectors are parallel to $y$-axis. The $x$-coordinates of these $n$ points will be distinct. You can sort the points according to their $x$-coordinates and group them to groups of 3.

Comment: Thanks, this has been a great help to me. However, how can I guarantee that no 3 points lie on a diagonal or horizontal line, as  specified by the problem?

Comment: Since 2 points determine a line. Out of $n$ points, you have $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ ways to pick two points and from a line joining them. If you don't want the two points lies on a horizontal or vertical or the two diagonal lines. Each line has 4 directions to avoid. This means when you rotate the coordinate system for an angle $\theta \in [0,\pi)$, there are only $4\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ angles which won't meet your requirement. As long as the number of angles you want to avoid is finite, there are always angles remain for what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've read this over for a while now but I don't really understand what you're trying to tell me.

Why does a line only have to avoid 4 directions? As far as I understood it, any line in the system is valid between two points so long as a 3rd point doesn't also lie on that same line, and this line can also be in any direction.

Am I making any sense here, or am I just horribly mistaken?

Comment: Wait a minute, forget what I say in the comment. In your question, you have stated the set of points are GIVEN to be in general position and no three of them are lying on a line. I've no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Wow, I feel like a real idiot now. Okay, thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** There are finitely many ways that we can 'triple' up the points to form $n/3$ triangles.

**Hint:** Consider the configuration which minimizes the total areas of all $n/3$ triangles. Claim: This works.

Comment: The second hint is brilliant. +1

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Can you find $3$ points whose triangle is guaranteed not to intersect any triangle formed from the other $n-3$ points?

> Find a line which separates $3$ of the points from the rest. Triangulate them. Proceed via induction.

Comment: That depends. Right now I've been playing with examples of different multiples of 3, and I can always find combinations which satisfy the conditions set by the question. 

However, I'm sure that as I extend it to infinity, this may not be so simple. I don't even know what a hyperplane is!

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking in $n$ dimensions. By *hyperplane* I meant *line*.

Comment: To simplify things, suppose we start by assuming the line is perpendicular to the $x$-axis. What happens?

Answer (score 2):

List the points in lexical order, such that $(x_i < x_{i+1})$ or $(x_i=x_{i+1} \wedge y_{i} < y_{i+1})$ for $i\in\{1,2,\ldots n-1\}$.  Then the grouping $\{\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6\},\ldots,\{n-2,n-1,n\}\}$ into sets of three contains no intersecting triangles.

For $n=3$, the theorem is trivially true.  Now assume the theorem is true for $n=3k$, and consider $3k+3$ points in general position.  The lexically smallest $3k$ points contain no intersecting triangles when grouped in this way, by the inductive hypothesis.  Moreover, the vertical line at $x=\frac{1}{2}(x_{3k} + x_{3k+1})$ separates the first $k$ triangles from the last triangle: all points but (at most) one of the first $k$ triangles lie to its left, and all points but (at most) one of the $(k+1)$-st triangle lie to its right.  We conclude that the final triangle cannot intersect any of the first $k$ triangles, and hence the theorem is true for $n=3k+3$.  The proof is complete by induction on $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the account I created to ask this was a guest account so I haven't been able to answer back to anything and ask other questions, and I don't think I have enough 'rep' to respond to answers directly.

achille hui, firstly, how did you derive the number of ways to join $3k$ points?

Secondly, can my co-ordinates consist of real numbers, or just natural ones, which would obviously make things much simpler.

And finally, why can't any two points create a vector parallel to x=0? I don't quite yet see how it would effect intersection, but I'm guessing that's what it's for.

Thanks, and again sorry for not being able to put my response where I need it to go.

Comment: Firstly: the exact number of ways to join n=3k points is irrelevant in achille hui's answer − the important thing is that it is finite. Secondly: reals or naturals, it doesn't matter here. And finally: the $y$-axis was chosen so that no such vector is parallel to $x=0$.

Comment: Well how do I show that number of ways SO THAT I can then go on to make the assumption that it's finite? I like to understand everything, and can't just take a statement(even if on faith I can assume it's true since people here are much smarter than I) and carry on with it without being able to see it for myself.

Secondly, thanks, but finally, I know that's why the y-axis was chosen. I'm asking why that's relevant to the intersection of triangles.

Thank you.

Comment: Oh I see. You weren't really asking why any two points can't create a vector parallel to $x=0$; you wanted to know why it's important that they don't. It's so that you can partition the plane into parallel slices, with each slice containing exactly three points. These three points form a triangle :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: My bad, I want to know how to derive $n(n−1)/2$, because until I can do that, I won't be willing to just accept that there are a finite amount of combinations(even though there are, if that makes sense).

Comment: You'll have to work that one out yourself. Don't worry, it's pretty easy.

Comment: @user65132 you can [merge your accounts](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge). If that doesn't work, there is a link to contact people who can help. Once you merge your accounts you will be able to comment on your question.

Comment: Thanks, robjohn.

TonyK, I have another problem now. Yes, distinct x co-ordinates allows for parallel slicing, but I've just re-read the problem and seen that it requires that no 3 points lie on the same line together.

The method reached so far ensures that no vertical lines are formed between any points, but do not necessarily ensure that they don't lie on the same horizontal line.

Comment: @user65132: please merge your accounts. Then you can extend your question rather than posting non-answers to do the same.

Answer (score -1):

Hall's marriage theorem trivialises the whole problem.
But that's my suggestion.

Comment: Can you explain more please ?

Comment: I feel rude directing you to wikipedia and planet math, but I think my explanation wouldn't do the theorem justice.

Basically, in the original marriage problem, we say that any problematic matching can be fixed with some simple switcheroo. So, we just have to extend it to groups of 3. (which is not difficult)

Answer (score -1):

There are finitely many slopes between pairs of points, so we may choose a line whose slope is not any of these. For ease of visualization we may choose it arbitrarily close to vertical.

Now sweep the line across the set of points from left to right. Since we will cross the points one at a time, we can cut the plane along this line as we pass each set of three points. Since each piece of the plane is convex, the triangle formed between the three points it contains lies within it. And since the pieces are disjoint, so are the triangles.